# How to load array values into tableview in iphone app using phonegap

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

Am new to phonegap. Now am using phonegap2.0 in my Lion mac. My xcode version is 4.3. Now i created Tableview for iphone app using html. And i created array with some values using JavaScript. Please see this below link: In this below link i have attach my html file and my Javascript file.

```
"http://pastie.org/4779045"
```

Now i want to load the array values in tableview. Please some body help me to load done this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a sample code

HTML part :

```
<!--HTML code -->
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="lstMyList">
</ul>
```

Javascript

```
/*javascript code*/
var i;
var names= new Array();
names[0] = "Gopi";
names[1] = "Vinoth";
names[2] = "Yuvaraj";

for (i=0;i<names.length;i++){
    $('#lstMyList').append('<li><a href="#">'+names[i]+'</a></li>');//append list items to the list view dynamically 
}
//If you add items to a listview, you'll need to call the refresh() method on it to update the styles and create any nested lists that are added.
$('#lstMyList').listview("refresh");
```

Hope its clear for you.

Comment: this will not work for me. not displaying my listview.